# GetElementById always returns null, no matter what object/website i try

Tags: c#, winforms, dom

Trying to automate actions on a website. I followed a tutorial and still no luck, no matter what website, tag or class I try it always gets null.

Saw a similar problem somewhere else where they suggested the website hadn't loaded so should add "while" section, which still didn't work for me.

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.simplesite.com/");
while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
     Application.DoEvents();
}
var myElement = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("_ctl0_Header2017_btnLogin");
myElement.InvokeMember("Click");
```

This is just a simple windows forms application. I've tried webBrowser1_Navigated and webBrowser1_DocumentCompletedmthods too.

[Inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRVcV.png)

Comment: try using getelementbyid in  webBrowser1_Navigated event

Comment: @UthistranSelvaraj, unfortunately, that didn't change anything. Thanks though!

Comment: Not sure if it's helpful, but looking at all the `Id` values in the returned document object, I don't see any that match the string you're searching for. But I know nothing about searching web pages. I used this to show the ids: `MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, webBrowser1.Document.All.Cast<HtmlElement>().Where(element => element?.Id != null).Select(element => element.Id)));`

Comment: @RufusL that is very useful, thanks. I don't understand why the id tags chrome showed aren't on that list. That's where the issue is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site is responding based on how it sees your browser's capabilities, which it determines based on the User Agent value passed in the request header. You need to set the User Agent string. The one the web browser control is sending is different than your Chrome/Firefox/IE sends.

I've added the Chrome User Agent string... you can find other User Agent strings here, under the Software section...
https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/

```
// call navigate and pass the latest Chrome User Agent string

webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.simplesite.com/", null, null, 
    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36\r\n");
while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
    // let's just wait a few milliseconds but it would be better
    // if we used the DocumentCompleted event
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100); 
 }
 var myElement = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("_ctl0_Header2017_btnLogin");
 myElement.InvokeMember("Click");
```

Comment: Happy to help. You may want to look into something like Postman or Fiddler... these are tools that let you manually build a request and see the back and forth communication. It can be really helpful when trying to figure out what's happening.